# pyannotate apply says "No files need to be modified." even if functions are not annotated

Tags: python

I have been using pytest https://github.com/kensho-technologies/pytest-annotate and have been following the process of:

```
pip install pytest-annotate

# Generate annotations by running your pytest tests as usual:
pytest --annotate-output=./annotations.json

# Apply those annotations using pyannotate:
pyannotate --type-info ./annotations.json .
```

But when I run the final step I can see

```
(base) C:\planner\planner-backend\service\planner>pyannotate -w --type-info ./annotations.json .
No files need to be modified.
```

The pytest collection step works apperently and a annotations.json was created.
Looking something like:

```
[
    {
        "path": "app/analyses.py",
        "line": 148,
        "func_name": "create",
        "type_comments": [
            "() -> Tuple[database.analysis.Analysis, int]",
            "() -> pyannotate_runtime.collect_types.NoReturnType"
        ],
        "samples": 6
    },
    {
        "path": "app/analyses.py",
        "line": 171,
        "func_name": "update",
        "type_comments": [
            "(int, int, str) -> Tuple[database.analysis.Analysis, int]"
        ],
        "samples": 1
    },
```

And 8000 lines more

When looking at the current directory both database and app are directories here. So inside /database/analysis.py there is the class Analysis

I'm devloping inside Docker and using pipenv, but I have tried invoking both inside and outside of docker and inside and outside of pipenv shell and nothing helps.

Do you have any suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: As far as I remember when working with the error it helped when I only applied it for one directory at a time

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of 2 possible reasons you get this error.

### Possible Issues

1. The function without type hints is not actually called by the tests. (`pyannotate`, and `monkeytype` for that matter, only generate `type-hints` for the code that was executed, not for all the code.)
2. You are not applying the `type-hints` to a Python file with the command: `pyannotate --type-info ./annotations.json .` (Note I am unsure about this, it may very well be correct.

Note there may be another reason you get this error .

### Solutions

In case of 1:
Write a test that calls the function for which no typing exists and run:

```
python -m pytest
```

Followed by the commands in case 2.

In case of 2:
I do not yet know how to apply the type hints to the root directory, yet to apply the `type-hints` to all the `.py` files in the `src/` and `tests/` folder, one can run:

```
for f in $(find src/ -name '*.py'); do pyannotate -w --python-version 3 --type-info type_info.json $f; done
for f in $(find tests/ -name '*.py'); do pyannotate -w --python-version 3 --type-info type_info.json $f; done
```

to apply the `type-hints` to all `.py` files in the subdirectories `src/` and `test/`.

More detailed instructions can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74278801/7437143), I hope this helps someone.