# MonkeyType: No traces found for module src.projectname.__main__

Tags: python, type-hinting

### Context

While trying to generate type hints for all python files in some project named `projectname`, I am experiencing some difficulties applying the stubs. The project directory is:

```
projectname/
|-- src/
|   |-- projectname/__main__.py
|   |-- projectname/some_folder/some_script.py
|-- tests/
|   |-- projectname/test_something.py
|   |-- projectname/another_folder/test_another_thing.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README.md
```

The main code is executed with:

```
python -m src.projectname
```

and the tests are executed with:

```
python -m pytest
```

### Output Attempt I

Based on [this](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType/issues/19) issue, I tried running:

```
monkeytype run src/snncompare/__main__.py
```

Which generates the `monkeytype.sqlite3` file in the root directory of the project. However, when I try to apply the generated type hints with:

```
monkeytype stub src.snncompare.__main__.py
monkeytype apply src.snncompare.__main__.py
```

or:

```
monkeytype stub src.snncompare.__main__
monkeytype apply src.snncompare.__main__
```

I get:

```
No traces found for module src.projectname.__main__
No traces found for module src.projectname.__main__.py
```

respectively. And for:

```
monkeytype apply src.snncompare
```

It says:

> No traces found for module src.snncompare

### Output Attempt II

Based on [this](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType/issues/64) issue, in which it says one should apply the stub to the "modulename" I tried running:

```
monkeytype run src/projectname/some_folder/some_script.py
monkeytype run src/projectname.some_folder.some_script.py
monkeytype run src/projectname.some_folder.some_script
monkeytype run some_script.py
monkeytype run some_script
```

from the root directory of the script, and they all produce the same error. I do not yet know exactly how to determine what the "modulename" of my project is.

### Attempt III

Based on [this](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType/issues/195#issuecomment-646401299) answer, I think I should create an additional file that calls the `__main__.py` file and executes its code, to be able to generate stubs for it, or the modules imported by it. However, that would seem in conflict with the quote:

> We don't collect traces for **main** because it could be different on subsequent runs and it would be confusing to look up such traces.

### Question

How can I apply the generated stubs to all the (touched) `.py` files in the project?

Answer (score 0):

### Misunderstanding

I think the key misunderstanding I had can be clarified with:
*MonkeyType currently does not automatically create typings for a Python project.*

### Issue

As described in the [issues](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType/issues/195#issuecomment-646401299) and the [readme](https://github.com/Instagram/MonkeyType), monkey type **only** generates type hints for the `some.py` files that a `main.py` file imports **and** uses. Even though I am relatively confident that a large fraction of my files are used when I run `__main__.py`, most of them are not directly imported by `__main__.py`. Instead, they are imported by the code that is imported by my `__main__.py`.

### Manual-"Solution"

To "automatically"/semi-manually generate the type hints, you need to write `another_python.py` file that:

1. imports each `other.py` file for which you want to automatically create type-hints.
2. Calls each function in every `other.py` file for which you want to automatically create type-hints.

### Bit of automation

Once could at least automate applying the stubs that you did find by walking over the directories and trying to apply the stubs if they exists:

```bash
monkeytype run src/projectname/__main__.py

# List all .py files in the project:
for f in $(find src/ -name '*.py'); do echo $f; done
# List all .py files in the project with `.` instead of `/`:
for f in $(find src/ -name '*.py'); do echo ${f//\//.}; done
# Apply monkeytype type hints to each file for which they were found.
for f in $(find src/ -name '*.py'); do monkeytype apply ${f//\//.}; done
```

### Additional Issues

I had a file `src/projectname/some_file.py` which contained `some_function():` which was definitely called by `__main__.py` yet no stubs like: `some_function() -> None:` were generated for this file. In total 1 out of 50 files were changed. I [retried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74278801/7437143) auto generating the stubs using the tests I wrote, with `pyannotate` by dropbox and that worked more effectively.