# Playwright typing annotation

Tags: python, playwright, type-annotation

Despite being for informational use, I am trying to setup typing annotations on my script, as it helps me to debug it later.

I am trying to set up Playwright's browser and context as the return of the following code, but I am not being successful:

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def run_browser() : 
    p = await async_playwright().start()
    browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = await browser.new_context(java_script_enabled=True,locale='pt-br')
    return context, p
```

What would I have to set on the `->` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Playwright 1.40.0 code passes Pyright 1.1.343 on Python 3.10.12:

```py
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, BrowserContext, Playwright


async def run_browser() -> tuple[BrowserContext, Playwright]:
    p = await async_playwright().start()
    browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    context = await browser.new_context(java_script_enabled=True, locale="pt-br")
    return context, p
```

See also [Automatically generating Python type annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416444/automatically-generating-python-type-annotations).

Comment: Thanks! I´ve updated my question to insert an image of the pylance feedback for another question!

Comment: For whatever reason, `BrowserContext` can be None according to your version and Pylance, so add `| None` if you want as the error suggests. I've rolled back the edit since it's not really part of your original question, more of a comment on my answer. See also [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). The error you're getting, for posterity, is `Expression of type "tuple[BrowserContext | None, Playwright]" cannot be assigned to return type "tuple[BrowserContext, Playwright]"`.

Comment: See also [Should "Edit:" in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged). I've added my packages in case that helps you determine why you've got that `| None` intersection. Pylance is built on Pyright, so it should give the same result if it's the same version of Playwright. What versions are you using?